# How do I enable SSL/HTTPS on KeystoneJS

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I have just started looking at KeystoneJS v5 and I am now trying to set up a [passport auth strategy](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/auth-passport/) locally (in my dev box) using Facebook. Unfortunately, in order for this to work the site must be served encrypted. How do I serve the KeystoneJS site using ssl/https on my dev machine? I'm on Ubuntu via WSLv1.

Comment: Are you sure? Based on https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/ HTTP addresses should work for `localhost`.

Comment: @AKX - I am sure... The setting for turning off HTTPS is there but disabled. And before you ask - the app is in dev mode.

Comment: I just noticed this: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/1783, maybe I can set it using the express options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting Nginx in front of it...